Is "He said he had had it two previous days" correct?
"I did it yesterday"

He said he had done it the day before/previously/earlier.

He said he had done it the previous day.


In my opinion all those are correct. Do you agree?
"I did it two days ago"

He said he had done it two days before/earlier or previously.

But can we say this?

He said he had had it two previous days.

To me it doesn't sound right. What do you think?

previously is wrong

reported speech 4? Is that from a textbook? He said he had done it previously. is fine but it doesn't mean before per se.It means at another time. You need better punctuation and sentence layout for your examples. Right now, they are pretty much illegible. Please don't ask these questions from a smartphone unless you are willing to edit them.

Ok, there is a sample edit that makes your question much clearer. Please try and follow a layout like that. Thanks. For low numbers (up to ten), write them out, don't use numbers.

Person 1: Did he have fish for lunch? Person 2: He said he had had it two days before.

"Last yesterday" is not a phrase that has meaning in English. What are you claiming it should mean? Two days ago? But simply put, that's not how we say it in English. It might sound reasonable to you, but it's just not accepted English. No one would know what you mean.
"He had had it two previous days" Well, that might make sense in the right context. Like, "Had he ever eaten mutton before the dinner Friday?" "Yes, he had had it the two previous days." That is, he had eaten mutton on Wednesday and Thursday, the two previous days with respect to the "reference day" of Friday.

Look. 2 days ago can be changed to 2 days earlier. Can 2 days ago be changed into 2 previous days or not?

@adam If you want to say "two days ago", you can say "two days previously", but not "two previous days". "Two previous days" means a span of 2 days, the day 2 days before and the day 1 day before. "Two days previously" means 2 days before. Sorry if that doesn't strike you as logical, but that's how the words are understood.

So we could change last month to the previous month or the month before or earlier or previously but last two month would be changed only to 2 months before or earlier or previously but not 2 previous months?

@adam Basically, yes. "Last month" means the month before the current month, whereas "previous month" means the month before some specified month, so they're not exactly interchangeable. Like if in May, I said, "Bob called me last month", I would mean he called in April. If I said, "Bob got a new job in February, after he quit his old job the previous month", the "previous month" there would mean the month before February, i.e. January, regardless of when I said it. But yes, if I said, "He quit his old job two months previously", that would mean two months before February, i.e. December.

If I said, "He was looking for a new job the two previous months", that would mean for two months before February, i.e. December and January. (It wouldn't make sense to say, "He quit his job the two previous months", as quitting a job just takes an instant or maybe a day, you wouldn't expect someone to spend two months quitting a job.)

The same rule with "next month" which we can change to "the next month" the following month" or "the month after or later" but "next two months" would be only changed to "two months after or later" but not "two following months or two next months"?

Also, if you are reporting what someone said earlier today, it would be "He said he did it yesterday". Again, context is all.

I know. But is my understanding correct?
